# C# WPF Changing background image depending on a conditional

Tags: c#, wpf, background

I'm trying to make a false error floating textbox that appears when some checkboxes aren't checked.

I have three floating textboxes (one for each conditional) and only one of them is working (doesn´t change more than one background image).

What am i doing wrong??

Thanks in advance.

The code so far:

```
            if (checkcaja.IsChecked == false && checkBoxbanderola.IsChecked == false && 
                checkBoxletra.IsChecked == false)
            {
                ImageBrush flechaerror = new ImageBrush();
                flechaerror.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(BaseUriHelper.GetBaseUri(this), "imagenes/iconoflechaerror.png"));
                this.Background = flechaerror;
                Etiquetatipoerror.Background = flechaerror;
            }
            else
            if (checkinterior.IsChecked == false && checkBoxexterior.IsChecked == false)
            {
                ImageBrush flechaerror2 = new ImageBrush();
                flechaerror2.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(BaseUriHelper.GetBaseUri(this), "imagenes/iconoflechaerror.png"));
                this.Background = flechaerror2;
                Etiquetaubicacionerror.Background = flechaerror2;
            }
            else
            if (checkrecomendado.IsChecked == false && checkBoxbarato.IsChecked == false && checkBoxmasluz.IsChecked == false && checkBoxmenosconsumo.IsChecked == false && checkBoxrgb.IsChecked == false)
            {
                ImageBrush flechaerror3 = new ImageBrush();
                flechaerror3.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(BaseUriHelper.GetBaseUri(this), "imagenes/iconoflechaerror.png"));
                this.Background = flechaerror3;
                Etiquetamoduloserror.Background = flechaerror3;
            }
            else
```

Comment: So you have a big if/else using a dozen different conditions? Have you simplified your conditions to make sure the backgrounds work (I.E. pick 1 or 2 simple conditions to set and test).. Are all 3 floating textboxes supposed to be active at once? If so, remove the else...

Comment: Your background images are all the same image. Is this your intention?

Comment: Just a general note: in WPF, you **don't** write code to create/update user interface. Instead, you **do** use XAML markup for that. Your task can be easily solved with triggers.

Comment: You are right, i will try with triggers...it seems easier.